# Is there a way I can get my docker-compose build command to auto-generate my Django requirements.txt?

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, pip, dockerfile

I'm using Django 2 and Python 3.7.  I have the following directory structure.

```
web
    - Dockerfile
    - manage.py  
    + maps  
    - requirements.txt  
    + static  
    + tests  
    + venv
```

"requirements.txt" is just a file I generated by running "pip3 freeze > requirements.txt".  I have the below Dockerfile for my Django container ...

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install

RUN apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN mkdir -p /app/

WORKDIR /app/

pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app/
```

I was wondering if there is a way to build my container such that it auto-generates and copies the correct requirements.txt file.  As you might guess, the line

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

I have attempted to include above causes the whole thing to die when running "docker-compose build" with the error

```
ERROR: Dockerfile parse error line 15: unknown instruction: PIP3
```

Comment: you can bash in the container and run pip/etc from the CLI there

Comment: Your `requirements.txt` file should be checked into source control and be part of your source tree.  That way you can always recreate a virtual environment by `pip install -r requirements.txt`, even if you're starting anew on a clean system (or a Docker image).

Comment: @DavidMaze, is there a way to do what you're describing when building the Dockerfile that will house the application?

Comment: Let's flip the question around.  When you start a new Docker image `FROM python`, it's totally clean and there are no packages installed.  If you ran `pip freeze`, it would return nothing.  In the isolated Docker image, how should it know what to install, to populate the `requirements.txt` file as you suggest?

Comment: I don't know.  That's why I asked the question.

Comment: I gave a more detailed [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60179920/10008173).  The `requirements.txt` (and/or `setup.py`) file is part of your source code, it's not something Docker can generate for you.

Comment: @Dave: David is right. requirements.txt should be part of source-code and should not be changed on run time.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense as your environment on docker container will be empty and rewrite your requirements.txt

You are also missing run

```
RUN pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: This isn't working.  If I remove my web/requirements.txt (my local file), adding the above the DOckerfile is not rebuilding it (I get the error, "ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder646403518/requirements.txt: no such file or directory")

Comment: Your project has requirements and requirements.txt file is where they are listed  so it should be kept as part of your source not to think about it as local .env file