# Running "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn" in a docker build says " stat /usr/local/bin/gunicorn: no such file or directory"

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, gunicorn

From the toplevel maps directory, I'm able to install the gunicorn extension ...

```
(venv) localhost:maps davea$ pip3 install gunicorn
Collecting gunicorn
  Downloading gunicorn-20.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 77 kB 1.2 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=3.0 in ./web/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from gunicorn) (45.1.0)
Installing collected packages: gunicorn
Successfully installed gunicorn-20.0.4
```

Below is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    ports:           # to access the container from outside
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn maps.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

  apache:
    restart: always
    build: ./apache/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    #volumes:
    #  - web-static:/www/static
    links:
      - web:web

  mysql:
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'maps_data'
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: 'chicommons'
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - "3406:3406"
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  my-db:
```

And then I have web/Dockerfile as follows ...

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install

RUN apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN mkdir -p /app/

WORKDIR /app/

RUN pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app/
```

However, when I build/start my docker instance, I'm told it can't find my "gunicorn" command ...

```
(venv) localhost:maps davea$ docker-compose up
Starting maps_web_1 ... 
Starting maps_web_1 ... error

ERROR: for maps_web_1  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/local/bin/gunicorn\": stat /usr/local/bin/gunicorn: no such file or directory": unknown

ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/local/bin/gunicorn\": stat /usr/local/bin/gunicorn: no such file or directory": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Docker container is a totally isolated environment.  Nothing you install on the host is visible inside the container; nothing that happens inside the container is accessible on the host.  There's ways to bridge this boundary (with `docker run -v` bind mounts) but that's not possible during the `docker build` phase.

In this example your local source tree has a `requirements.txt` file that lists out the packages that need to be installed when the container is created.  (The `RUN pip freeze` line has no effect; the `COPY` on the line after it copies it from your local source tree.)  It's enough to add the dependency to the `requirements.txt` file

```
gunicorn
```

In your development environment, you can re-run `pip install -r requirements.txt` to update the packages installed in your virtual environment.  When you re-run `docker build`, having this line in the `requirements.txt` file will cause it to be installed when the package is built.

You can clean up the Dockerfile a little bit.  The resulting Dockerfile would be a pretty typical one for Python packages with C dependencies:

```sh
# Start from a totally clean environment with Python installed,
# but no non-system libraries and nothing from your host system.
FROM python:3.7-slim

# Install C dependencies.
# It's important to do apt-get update and install in the
# same command.  It's more efficient to only do it once.
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      gcc \
      libmariadb-dev \
      libmariadb-dev-compat

# Update pip
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

# Create the application directory and point there
# (WORKDIR will implicitly create it)
WORKDIR /app/

# Install all of the Python dependencies.  These are
# listed, one to a line, in the requirements.txt file,
# possibly with version constraints.  Having this as
# a separate block allows Docker to not repeat it if
# only your application code changes.
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy in the rest of the application.
COPY . .

# Specify what port your application uses, and the
# default command to use when launching the container.
EXPOSE 8000
CMD /usr/local/bin/gunicorn maps.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000
```